# Show answer elsewhere

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I've searched several topics, but couldn't really find my desired answer. I am using Google Sites for making (financial) calculations, and started of using this simple template found on this website.

```
<script>
  function calcul(){
    var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=x+y;
  }
</script>

<form action="" id="nothing">
  <input type="text" id="value1">
  <input type="text" id="value2">
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="but" onclick="calcul()" />
</form>

<p id="answer"></p>
```

I understand this piece of scripting, but I want to show the answer elsewhere. So for example, instead of clicking on Calculate and just show the answer on the next paragraph, I want it like this:

The answer is: `<p id="answer"></p>`.

So on the same line, with 'The answer is' already showing and the answer/number showing after clicking on calculate.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: what's not working? move the `<p id="answer"></p>` to wherever you want on the page, the code should work the same

Comment: Just add "The answer is:" to your markup. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `<p id="answer"></p>` to a `<span id="answer"></span>` and add "the answer is" before it in the HTML code.

Comment: This is actually a better way imho because it keeps a mathematical function within the realms of maths without adding strings to it.

Comment: Thanks! I already came across the <span> code, but didn't understand how to 'plug it in' properly.

Answer (score 6):

Modify your output:

```
var msg = "The answer is: ";
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML= msg + (x + y);
```

Or modify your markup:

```
<p>The answer is: <span id="answer">0</span></p>
```

Initially `0` will be the answer, until you run `calcul` for the first time.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling that I could put `id="answer"` between these <> brackets, but that tutorial didn't cover `<span etcetc></span>`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Because of the use of `<p>`, your answer can go anywhere you put it on the page, but it will always be in its own paragraph. If you use `<span>` instead, it can go on the same line:

```
The answer is: <span id="answer"></span>
```